# Give a general formula for nth and mth derivative in (0,0) using Taylor.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative

Given $f(x,y)=\frac{x}{1-2xy^{2}}$, how can I give a general formula for $D_{n,m}=\frac{\partial f^{n+m}}{\partial x^{n}\partial y^{m}}(0,0),\:\:\:n,m\geq0$ using Taylor?

Where should I begin?

Comment: By induction...try for several combinations of m and n

Comment: recall geometric series....